# Observing strange behavior with `allow` and `have_received` with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I'm having issues using `allow` and `have_received` in my specs

I have a model called `Obj` that has a `belongs_to` relationship with a model called `Parent`. The `Parent` model has a `has_many` relationship with `Obj`.

In the `Obj` model, I've defined a method called `child_method`. In the `Parent` model, I've defined a method called `calls_child_method`, which iterates through each `Obj` associated with it and has them call `child_method`

I'm writing a spec to test this behavior as follows, but it keeps failing:

```
describe 'parent calls_child_method' do
  let(:obj) { Obj.create }

  before do
    allow(obj).to receive(:child_method)
  end

  it 'should call child_method' do
    obj.parent.calls_child_method
    expect(obj).to have_received(:child_method)
  end
end
```

Output:

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

However, this seems to pass when I use `allow_any_instance_of` to do the spy/stubbing:

```
describe 'parent calls_child_method' do
  let(:obj) { Obj.create }

  before do
    allow(obj).to receive(:child_method)
  end

  it 'should call child_method' do
    expect_any_instance_of(Obj).to receive(:child_method)
    obj.parent.calls_child_method
  end
end
```

or if I call the child method directly:

```
describe 'parent calls_child_method' do
  let(:obj) { Obj.create }

  before do
    allow(obj).to receive(:child_method)
  end

  it 'should call child_method' do
    obj.child_method
    expect(obj).to have_received(:child_method)
  end
end
```

In all of this, I've verified that the instance of the `Obj` that gets created is actually calling `child_method` by using `byebug` debugging to see that it is being called.

Can someone help me understand why the spec/spy  is behaving like this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was puzzling me for many years. This is how I understand what is happening.

In your failing case `obj` is a reference to your newly created `Obj.create`. By calling `expect(obj).to have_received(:child_method)` it is expected that EXACT reference `obj` should receive `child_method`.

When `obj`’s parent receives `calls_child_method` it iterates through each Obj associated with it. Most probably it calls `parent.objs` which will trigger a new DB call. In your case that will find your `obj`, but will have a different reference to it. And that different reference will be the one that gets `child_method`

That’s why technically your object does receive the method call, but through a different reference. As a result your expectation fails:(

`expect_any_instance_of(Obj)` solves the problem. However it’s usually better to avoid it.

Your last example is successful because your expectation and method call is using the same object/reference.